# Twitter API multiple terms in search query

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to get every tweet from `mcdonalds` that isn't a `retweet` nor a `reply` from someone else.

I'm using `search_tweets.py` from the official Twitter GitHub and as filter rule I use:
--filter-rule "from:mcdonalds AND -is:retweet". However, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:searchtweets.result_stream:HTTP Error code: 422: {"error":{"message":"There were errors processing your request: Reference to invalid field 'filter' (at position 2), Rules must contain a non-negation term (at position 1), Rules must contain at least one positive, non-stopword clause (at position 1), Reference to invalid operator 'filter'. Operator is not available in current product or product packaging. Please refer to complete available operator list at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/rules-and-filtering/operators-by-product. (at position 2)","sent":"2021-01-30T15:43:17+00:00","transactionId":"00fa261b00dc1b96"}}
ERROR:searchtweets.result_stream:Request payload: {'query': '-filter:retweets', 'maxResults': 10}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search_tweets.py", line 212, in <module>
    main()
  File "search_tweets.py", line 207, in main
    for tweet in stream:
  File "/home/gianluca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/searchtweets/utils.py", line 140, in write_result_stream
    yield from write_ndjson(_filename, stream)
  File "/home/gianluca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/searchtweets/utils.py", line 95, in write_ndjson
    for item in data_iterable:
  File "/home/gianluca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/searchtweets/result_stream.py", line 222, in stream
    self.execute_request()
  File "/home/gianluca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/searchtweets/result_stream.py", line 272, in execute_request
    resp = request(session=self.session,
  File "/home/gianluca/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/searchtweets/result_stream.py", line 110, in retried_func
    raise requests.exceptions.HTTPError
requests.exceptions.HTTPError
```

Credentials are correct and if I only search for `"from:mcdonalds"` I'll actually get the tweets.

Comment: Did you check the documentation referenced in the error message? there is no such operator as `filter:` in the premium or enterprise search APIs (or v2 search), which is what that package works with. What was the full search query you submitted?

Comment: you could use `-is:retweet` but since you don’t have a specific search term / word in the query, that will not work on its own.

Comment: @AndyPiper that must be the problem than, thank you